# Unable to access key value pairs in js object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Unable to access key value pairs in js object. I'm trying to access current day from `dayName` but I'm unable to do so. It is showing `undefined` when I'm trying to access the `dayName` via `dayNum` key.

**JS**

```js
app.get("/", (req, res) => {       
    let dayName = {
        "1" : "Monday",
        "2" : "Tuesday",
        "3" : "Wednesday",
        "4" : "Thursday",
        "5" : "Friday",
        "6" : "Saturday",
        "0" : "Sunday"
    }
    
    let today = new Date();
        
    let dayNum = today.getDay().toString();
    console.log(dayName.dayNum);

    res.render("list", {
        day : dayName.dayNum
    });
});
```

**EJS**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do List</title>
</head>
    
<body>
    <h1>Today is <%= day %></h1>
</body>
    
</html>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image: console output]

[image: browser output]

Comment: In console.log use dayName[dayNum] instead of dayName.dayNum because its check dayNum in dayName not dayNum value. its take dayNum as key of dayName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the square bracket notation. With the dot notation `dayName.dayNum` we are looking for the value with key `"dayNum"` inside the object and since it does not have any such key, it returns `undefined`. If we use the bracket notation, `dayNum` will be evaluated to the correct key before object access. See [Dot Notation vs. Bracket Notation](https://codeburst.io/javascript-quickie-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-333641c0f781)

```js
res.render("list", {
    day : dayName[dayNum]
});
```

Also I would recommend using an array instead of object for `dayName`

```js
const dayName = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping out brother. but can you explain a bit why it was not working without brackets I'm a bit curious? and yeah I find your recommendation of using an array instead of the object helpful.

Comment: Sure, Apologies for not adding it to the answer. So in our case when we did `dayName.dayNum`, we are actually trying to access value with key `dayNum` value from the object. Since our object does not have any such key, It returned undefined. In the case of bracket notation, the key is dynamic, meaning it will first evaluate the `dayNum` inside the bracket and get the appropriate key to look inside the object. You can read more about it from https://codeburst.io/javascript-quickie-dot-notation-vs-bracket-notation-333641c0f781

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.get("/", (req, res) => {       
    let dayName = {
        "1" : "Monday",
        "2" : "Tuesday",
        "3" : "Wednesday",
        "4" : "Thursday",
        "5" : "Friday",
        "6" : "Saturday",
        "0" : "Sunday"
    }
    
    let today = new Date();
        
    let dayNum = today.getDay().toString();
    console.log(dayName.dayNum);

    res.render("list", {
        day : dayName.dayNum
    });
});
```